# Reading input data to array(s) with multiple delimiters and headings

Tags: python, arrays, string, parsing, delimiter

I'm trying to formulate a parser in python to read an input file and then assemble the results into several arrays.

The data has the following structure:

```
Some_numbers
1
5
6
some_vector
[-0.99612937 -0.08789929  0.        ]
[-0.99612937 -0.08789929  0.        ]
[ -9.99999987e-01   1.61260621e-04   0.00000000e+00]
Some_data
1239    #int    
671 
471 
851 
S4RS    #string
517 
18  
48  
912 
S4RS
```

So far the methods that I have tried are:

```
text_file = 'C:\AA\aa.txt'
lines = open(text_file).read().splitlines()
numbers = []
Vector = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith('Some_numbers'):
        continue
        numbers.append(line)
    if line.startswith('some_vector'):
        continue
        Vector.append(line)
```

Problems I have encountered are the:
 1) Having multiple delimiters
 2) Trying to split the data according to the relevant sections

I have also tried using the np.genfromtxt along with countless hours trawling the internet.

Your comments and advice are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure about any in-built or library functions that can do the trick, but there are some apparent issue in your `for` loop .

First, a statement after `continue` inside the `if` block - `numbers.append(line)` (or the vector equivalent) . This statement will never get executed, since continue would send the control back to the starting of the `for` loop , with the `counter` variable incremented.

Second, you are not reading based on `sections` , which is what your input contains, though I would say you are not reading anything at all pretty much.

A sample code that would work (for numbers and vectors is) -

```
text_file = 'C:\AA\aa.txt'
lines = open(text_file).read().splitlines()
numbers = []
Vector = []
section = ''
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith('Some_numbers'):
        section = 'numbers'
        continue
    elif line.startswith('some_vector'):
        section = 'vectors'
        continue
    elif section == 'numbers':
        numbers.append(line) # or numbers.append(int(line)) , whichever you want
    elif section == 'vectors':
        Vector.append(line)
```

Please note, the above code is only for numbers and vectors, other sections will need to be coded by you.